# How to make string list to "string array"

Tags: c#

This is what I want to convernt: {"apple", "banana"} to "["apple", "banana"]"

I have tried convert string list to string array first, then convert string array to string, but did not work.

```
var testing = new List<string> {"apple", "banana"};
var arrayTesting = testing.ToArray();
var result = arrayTesting.ToString();
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert that *list* of strings to a string with brackes? Or do you really have a *string* containing the curly brackets as well?

Comment: It sounds like you want something like `"\"" + string.Join(", ", testing.Select(item => "\"" + item + "\"")) + "\""`

Comment: `.ToArray()` will convert the `List` to an array of strings. Modify your `list` to `List` and add a `;` at the end of the first line

Comment: I want to convert a list of strings to array first, then add double quote to array

Comment: @degant
I fixed as you suggested.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Where does the List<string> come from? It's possible a string literal and a simple replace is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`string.Join(String, String[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) method like below to get a `,` separated string values (like `csv` format)

```
var stringifiedResult = string.Join(",", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, should work;

```
    var testing = new List<string> { "apple", "banana" };
    var arrayTesting = testing.ToArray<string>();
    var result = string.Join(",", arrayTesting);
```

Comment: you don't really need the `arrayTesting` line in there...`Join` will work on any `IEnumerable`, like the `testing` list.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("\"[");
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayTesting.Length; i++)
            {
                string item = arrayTesting[i];

                sb.Append("\"");
                sb.Append(item);
                if (i == arrayTesting.Length - 1)
                {
                    sb.Append("\"]");
                }
                else
                    sb.Append("\",");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

Comment: Your result is StringBuilder, I want a string type

Comment: Call ToString() Method on the StringBuilder Object to get the required string.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of converting it to an array, you could use a linq operator on the list to write all the values into a string.

```
string temp = "";
testing.ForEach(x => temp += x + ", ");
```

This will leave you with a single string with each value in the list separated by a comma.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but string.Join already exists and won't create a string with a trailing comma.  Yours will leave a trailing comma